Wpf MenuItem's parent is null in mvvm mode
I want to get the parent of menuitem in mvvm mode, so that I can add the input binding on the parent control.Here is my code.
ViewModel
namespace MenuItemMinimumDemo
{
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
            var menuItem = new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "File" };
            menuItem.Children.Add(new MenuItemViewModel { Header = "Open"});
            MenuItems.Add(menuItem);

        }
    }

    public class MenuItemViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _header;
        public string Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _header, value); }
        }

        public static ICommand ClickAction { get; set; } = new DelegateCommand<MenuItem>((menu) =>
        {
            var parentIsNull = menu.Parent == null;
        });
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> Children { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
    }
}

Xaml
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ClickAction}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
    </Grid>

When I clicked the the Open button, I found that parentIsNull is true. Is there any way to set the relationship between menu item and sub menu items?

The item view model should have a reference to the parent item view model if you want to do stuff with it's parent. Alternatively, you could handle a routed command in the parent menuitem.
